# Add extra fields to create and update role in filament-authentication package

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, roles, filamentphp

I want to add extra fields to roles in package filament-authentication

I am only able to add it in migrations

Its says its has extendable resource views but doesn't mention how to extend it
https://filamentphp.com/plugins/user-role-resource-management

I am new to laravel filamentphp

Can anyone guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point every answer is missing is that all packages have a config file that's published in config directory.

In order to extend a package we just have to create a new Resource/Page, inherit and override it's functionality.

Finally, we need to replace path/namesapce in the config of that package with the new Resource/Page we just override.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra fields, first add your columns using migrations - if want to add.

OR

To extend the package layout, you can create a new [Filament Page](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/pages/getting-started#creating-a-page) and extends the Package view.

### Steps

Create a new page using `php artisan make:filament-page Profile`
- don't attach with any resource

It will create a file inside the `App\Filament\Pages\Profile.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages;

use Filament\Pages\Page;
use Phpsa\FilamentAuthentication\Pages\Profile as PagesProfile;

class Profile extends PagesProfile
{
    // 
}
```

You can follow more details on this [link](https://filamentphp.com/tricks/customizing-filament-breezy-registration-profile-page), how to extend package functionality and view.